# Como criar strings multi-linha em C++?

Tags: c++, string, sintaxe

Tem alguma forma de imprimir a saída, por exemplo de um texto, sem precisar ficar imprimindo linha por linha?

Por exemplo, em Python:

```
print("""
Meu nome eh Guilherme, 
tenho 19 anos, faço aniversário em Nov.
Estudo o curso de ciência da computação.
(+ 4 linhas abaixo)
""")
```

Teria como fazer algo parecido em C++? Ou eu teria que ficar usando `cout` e `\n` para fazer alguma coisa parecida?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o símbolo já usado para escapar caracteres especiais para indicar que o texto continua na próxima linha.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "isto é um teste \
de texto multi linha \
que pode ser usado em qualquer contexto de string";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fHs02U). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MultiLinecpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/MultiLine.cpp).

Note que a tabulação faria parte do texto então tive que colar no início da linha, mas isso é igual a outras linguagens (já vi algumas que desconsideram a indentação normal, estranho que Python não faz isso, é a linguagem que mais deveria fazer).

Também é possível usar assim:

```
"isto é um teste "
"de texto multi linha "
"que pode ser usado em qualquer contexto de string"
```

Mas em geral não produz o que deseja, já que não tem quebra de linha, e fica esquisito ter que colocar na mão um `\n`. Aí obviamente pode indentar cada parte do texto fora das aspas.

A performance não é afeta. Pelo contrário, se fizer uma concatenação pode afetar, se o compilador não conseguir fazer uma otimização porque passaria ter um processamento em vez dessa forma que é só uma sintaxe diferente.

Comment: Noooooossa, salvou absurdamente!! Muitíssimo obr!

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida só, em quesito de performance e eficiência qual eh melhor? linha por linha igual eu fiz ou desse jeito que perguntei?

Comment: Não muda nada, é só sintaxe.